# Mono broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, mono

My verison of Ubuntu is 16.04
When I tried to abort Mono installation I got some problems after this. ( And now I realized that abort is not very good way to stop installation )
I tried to `sudo apt-clean`, remove apt list folders and fix it with `sudo apt-get update`. Nothing happend.

When I tried to install something I got error:

```
scp@keter:~$ sudo apt-get install lsof
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-runtime-sgen : Depends: mono-runtime-common (= 5.10.1.4-0xamarin1+ubuntu1604b1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I'm trying to fix all with `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
scp@keter:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/898 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package mono-runtime-common (--configure):
 package mono-runtime-common is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-runtime-sgen:
 mono-runtime-sgen depends on mono-runtime-common (= 5.10.1.4-0xamarin1+ubuntu1604b1); however:
  Package mono-runtime-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mono-runtime-sgen (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-runtime:
 mono-runtime depends on mono-runtime-sgen (= 5.10.1.4-0xamarin1+ubuntu1604b1); however:
  Package mono-runtime-sgen is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mono-runtime (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-corlib4.5-cil:
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil depends on mono-runtime (>= 5.10.1.4); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil depends on mono-runtime (<< 5.10.1.5); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: error processing package libmono-corlib4.5-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-system-security4.0-cil:
 libmono-system-security4.0-cil depends on libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-corlib4.5-cil is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-system-security4.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-i18n4.0-cil:
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil depends on libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-corlib4.5-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil depends on mono-runtime (>= 5.10.1.4); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil depends on mono-runtime (<< 5.10.1.5); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-i18n4.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil:
 libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil dNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                       epends on libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-corlib4.5-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil depends on libmono-i18n4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-i18n4.0-cil is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-system-xml4.0-cil:
 libmono-system-xml4.0-cil depends on libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-corlib4.5-cil is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil:
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil depends on libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-corlib4.5-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil depends on libmono-system-security4.0-cil (>= 1.0); however:
  Package libmono-system-security4.0-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil depends on libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (>= 3.12.0); however:
  Package libmono-system-xml4.0-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil depends on mono-runtime (>= 5.10.1.4); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil depends on mono-runtime (<< 5.10.1.5); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-systNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
         No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                     em4.0-cil:
 libmono-system4.0-cil depends on libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-corlib4.5-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-system4.0-cil depends on libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-system4.0-cil depends on libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (>= 3.12.0); however:
  Package libmono-system-xml4.0-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-system4.0-cil depends on mono-runtime (>= 5.10.1.4); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.
 libmono-system4.0-cil depends on mono-runtime (<< 5.10.1.5); however:
  Package mono-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-system4.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmono-security4.0-cil:
 libmono-security4.0-cil depends on libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-corlib4.5-cil is not configured yet.
 libmono-security4.0-cil depends on libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-system4.0-cil is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmono-security4.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-4.0-gac:
 mono-4.0-gac depends on libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-corlib4.5-cil is not configured yet.
 mono-4.0-gac depends on libmono-security4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6); however:
  Package libmono-security4.0-cil is not configured yet.
 mono-4.0-gac depends on libmono-system-security4.0-cil (>= 1.0); however:
  Package libmono-system-security4.0-cil is not configured yet.
 mono-4.0-gac depends on libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1); however:
  Package libmono-system4.0-cil is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mono-4.0-gac (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-gac:
 mono-gac depends on mono-4.0-gac (= 5.10.1.4-0xamarin1+ubuntu1604b1); however:
  Package mono-4.0-gac is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mono-gac (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mono-runtime-common
 mono-runtime-sgen
 mono-runtime
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil
 libmono-system-security4.0-cil
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil
 libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil
 libmono-system-xml4.0-cil
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil
 libmono-system4.0-cil
 libmono-security4.0-cil
 mono-4.0-gac
 mono-gac
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm a novice in UNIX based OS's, so, maybe I don't know something. ( We all don't know something ), please help!

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy mono-runtime-common  mono-runtime-sgen  mono-runtime  libmono-corlib4.5-cil  libmono-system-security4.0-cil  libmono-i18n4.0-cil  libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil  libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil  libmono-system4.0-cil  libmono-security4.0-cil  mono-4.0-gac  mono-gac` to the question.

Comment: Could try removing the error unconfigured packages, I think `apt-get remove  mono-runtime-common
 mono-runtime-sgen
 mono-runtime
 libmono-corlib4.5-cil
 libmono-system-security4.0-cil
 libmono-i18n4.0-cil
 libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil
 libmono-system-xml4.0-cil
 libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil
 libmono-system4.0-cil
 libmono-security4.0-cil
 mono-4.0-gac
 mono-gac` might  be appropriate. Then an update & try installing (uninterrupted) again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended Up With Full Reinstalling of OS. Thank's for comments, but, that didn't work as well.